# Popen drops keys which don't start with a letter from env

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am having difficulty passing some environment variables to a process using `Popen`. Consider the following code snippet:

```
from subprocess import Popen

env = dict()
env['VALID_VAR'] = 'some value'
env['1INVALID_VAR'] = 'other value'

proc = Popen(['./test'], env=env)
```

I'd expect the new process to have both `VALID_VAR` and `1INVALID_VAR` as environment variables, but `1INVALID_VAR` gets dropped.

My question is why does python drops the key and who could I pass such key to a child process otherwise.

#### System information

OS: `Ubuntu 17.10` 
Python: `3.6.3`

---

For reference this is the code (C) I used to check which variables the child process gets:

```
include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("printenv");
}
```

Comment: Testing with python 3.10.6 on Fedora 35 I am not able to reproduce this, VALID_VAR and 1INVALID_VAR are both present.